# Getting Compile Error CS1545, After update the NuGet Package of after StackExchange.Redis to 2.6.96

Tags: redis

> error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event
> 'ConfigurationOptions.EndPoints' is not supported by the language;
> try directly calling accessor methods
> 'ConfigurationOptions.get_EndPoints()' or
> 'ConfigurationOptions.set_EndPoints(?)'

Answer (score 0):

It is because `StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions` is using keyword `init` which is supported in C# 9 and later
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs#L389C8-L389C8

`public EndPointCollection EndPoints { get; init; } = new EndPointCollection();`

so you need to change your project's C# LangVersion to 9 or higher.

You can do that in [csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#edit-the-project-file) file or in [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)